# How to config JedisPoolConfig with redis.clients.jedis.UnifiedJedis

Tags: java, redis, apache-commons, jedis

I have seen follwing example.

```
  final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = buildPoolConfig();
JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "localhost");

private JedisPoolConfig buildPoolConfig() {
    final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(128);
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(128);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(16);
    poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
    poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    poolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(60).toMillis());
    poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(30).toMillis());
    poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
    poolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);
    return poolConfig;
}

try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
    // do operations with jedis resource
}
```

It returns only  redis.clients.jedis.Jedis client, but I am using "jedis-4.0.0.jar" and I want use redis.clients.jedis.UnifiedJedis client with pooling mechanism is there any way to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `JedisPoolConfig` you need `ConnectionPoolConfig`.

Also, since Jedis 4.0 you can't just send host in the respective constructor. So use any other alternate.

> WARNING: This constructor only accepts a uri string as url.

```
final ConnectionPoolConfig poolConfig = buildPoolConfig();
UnifiedJedis jedis = new JedisPooled(poolConfig, "localhost", 6379);

private ConnectionPoolConfig buildPoolConfig() {
    final ConnectionPoolConfig poolConfig = new ConnectionPoolConfig();
    // change poolConfig as you want
    return poolConfig;
}

// do operations with (unified) jedis object
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, It is working Thanks a lot again!!!!.